# SQL count(*) giving wrong answer when used with group by

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I run this query the count(0) returns 21 for the set with zip='80005'.

```
select zip, avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(0) from values group by zip order by zip
```

There are really 109 rows with zip='80005'.

The following two queries both show 109 rows and they also return different values for min, max, and avg.

```
select avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(value) from values where zip='80005'

select zip, avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(value) from values group by zip having zip='80005'
```

There are no nulls for value.

Is there any reason why the first query is returning the wrong number of rows in the set for zip='80005'?

Maybe this is a bug in Postgresql.

Comment: is not that count(0) = 21 the number of rows that it is returning your query?, you dont have a where in the first query

Comment: I don't need a where clause in the first query.  I want to compute avg, min, and max for each zip code.  The results from the first query for zip 80005 differ from what I find when I search for that zip 80005 alone.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `count(*)` not `count(0)`...

Comment: count(*) and count(0) give the same result:  21

Comment: @Chris: There is no difference between `COUNT(*)`, `COUNT(0)` or `COUNT(1)` in PostgreSQL. The `COUNT` function counts all non-NULL values. `COUNT(*)` doesn't evaluate the values, and works like `COUNT(0)`. However, if you use `COUNT(value)` you'll get the count of non-NULL values. `COUNT(*)` and other fixed value non-NULL counts return the number of affected rows.

Comment: These will always give the same result, so it isn't the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`Count(1)`, `Count(*)` and `Count([field])` all work.

There was one source I read that said there was a performance difference between `Count(1)` and `Count(*)` (allegedly, `count(*)` required more processing), however, there seems to be evidence at least for Postgress & TSQL that it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What ever makes you think that? COUNT(data field) requires the query to fetch the data field, COUNT(*) or COUNT(some constant) do not. All versions require a sequential scan of the table, though, in order to access MVCC/transaction information to see if the row is visible to the current transaction.

Comment: Read about count(*) versus count(1) here (scroll down to the performance tip, or just CTRL+F for count(1)): http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php.  Maybe the documentation is wrong, or maybe it's different for different sql dialects.  I guess you could test it out to make sure.

Comment: Um, it does not name a database server nor does it cite a source. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html for Postgres. Also, please note the case where an unoptimized engine might check the expression `1` for NULLness, making it slower than a simple row count with COUNT(*).

Comment: Oh, haha, there actually *was* such a case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1 (search for 'oracle')

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, this looks like a bug, hard to say without seeing your data.

You could try and narrow down the source of the problem.

If this :-

```
  select zip, avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(value) 
  from values group by zip having zip='80005'
```

returns 109, but this :-

```
select zip, avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(0) 
from values group by zip order by zip
```

returns 21 for 80005, what is returned for 80005 when you do this :-

```
  select zip, avg(value), min(value), max(value), count(value) 
  from values group by zip
```

Answer (score 0):

Look and see if you have records with zip 80005b where *b* is one or more trailing blanks. Those would collate somewhere else in your grouped zip list. I believe by default PG will ignore trailing blanks when testing two strings for equality, but not in a `GROUP BY`. (Do you have a sanity check constraint on the zip field?)